# How do I copy an image with multiple channels?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with opencv2 over python.  I am trying to copy an image in the YCrCb format but it is only copying the Cb channel

I checked the channel count by printing the shape of the copied image, it's still 3 channels, it's just the colors are only Cb

```
img = cv.imread('C:\\Users\\Anon\\Pictures\\CV\\IMAG1227\\pryramid_4.bmp')

print(img.shape)
for x in range(0, 2):
    img = cv.pyrDown(img)

YCrCb_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)


height, width, channel = YCrCb_img.shape

print(YCrCb_img.shape)

copy = YCrCb_img.copy()
    print(copy.shape)

cv.imwrite('C:\\Users\\Anon\\Pictures\\CV\\IMAG1227\\YCr_CB_copyTest.bmp', copy)
```

The resulting image colors looks the same as the Cb picture in the below image
[image: i]

The shape returned is

`print(YCrCb_img.shape)` => (300, 400, 3)

`print(copy.shape)` => (300, 400, 3)

Comment: You realize that the Cb and Cr channels have been pseudo-coloured and saved individually right?  You're converting the entire image and saving that image to disk.  The image on Wikipedia shows you each channel individually.

Answer (score 0):

**In order to access individual channel use cv2.split()  function**

like here

```
YCrCb_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
y,cr,cb = cv.split(YCrCb_img)
```

now check the shape of y,cr,cb seperately you will get the result as you guess if  i am not wrong.

```
print(y.shape)
```